# Why do I need to update my contact details before Arxiv submissions

Tags: arxiv

Question as in the title. What are the practical or legal reasons Arxiv asks to check a box before each submission, affirming that my affiliation and contact details are still up to date?

Having to check a box makes it look like much more than just *keeping up the record.* In fact, why do they even need my affiliation in the first place?